# Page configuraion is not in its right place (page_layout/catalog_category_view.xml)?

Tags: layout, page-layouts

This file (vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/frontend/page_layout/catalog_category_view.xml) belongs to namespace xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"

Files with this namespace are usually placed in the view/[area]/layout directory.

Is this a bug, or does it solve some issue?

https://github.com/magento/magento2-page-builder/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/PageBuilder/view/frontend/page_layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

The use of xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" in the catalog_category_view.xml file from the Magento Page Builder module indicates that this file is defining a page layout configuration.

By default, page layout configuration files are stored in the view/[area]/layout directory of a Magento module or theme. However, it is possible to specify a different directory for page layout configuration files using the page_layouts section of the module's module.xml file.

In the case of the Magento Page Builder module, it appears that the catalog_category_view.xml file is defining a custom page layout for the category view page, and therefore it may have been intentionally placed in a different location to better organize the module's files.

So, it's not a bug, but rather a deliberate decision made by the module's developers to organize the file in a different location.